# Access Nested Object - ReactJs

Tags: javascript, json, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to parse and map nested object which looks like this:

```
{
  "country": "germany",
  "timeline": {
    "cases": {
      "1/22/20": 0,
      "1/23/20": 0,
      "1/24/20": 0,
      "1/25/20": 0,
      "1/26/20": 0,
      "1/27/20": 1,
      "1/28/20": 4,
      "1/29/20": 4,
      "1/30/20": 4
    }
  }
}
```

This is my first attempt, where I have tried a few variations of inserting response in a component.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

class Chart extends Component {
  state = {
    historyStats: [],
    // error: true
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('https://corona.lmao.ninja/v2/historical/germany')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then((data) => {
      this.setState({ historyStats: data })
    })
    .catch(console.log)
  }

  render() {
    const {historyStats} = this.state;
    console.log(Object.values(historyStats));

    return (
      <div>

       {Object.values(historyStats).map(test => (
        <p>{test[0]} | {test[1]}</p>
      ))}
      </div>
    )
  }
}


export default Chart;
```

How can I achieve output like this:

> test[0]} = **1/22/20** - Date
>
> test[1] = **0** - Value

Help appreciated
Thanks

Comment: what is the expected result that you want? because you are only showing in your return something like
`<p> germany |  Object <p> `
because `test[1]` is the object from the key `timeline`

Comment: I want to output, something like this:
{test[0]} = **1/22/20** | {test[1] = **0**

Comment: @BloodOverdrive Edit the post and add the output there , it's a bit unreadable from here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, the problem is that you are not accessing your items correctly and you define `historyStats` as an array but the response is an object, ideally, the best thing to do, is transform the data into what you want. lets do it.

also lets use [Object Entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) in order to get our `[key, value]`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

class Chart extends Component {
  state = {
    historyStats: [],
    // error: true
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('https://corona.lmao.ninja/v2/historical/germany')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then((data) => {
      // basically, lets get what it is important, the CASES.
      const { timeline } = data;
      const { cases } = timeline;

      // now cases is an object, lets transform it into an array of 2 entries, the key and value.
      const newHistoryStats = Object.entries(cases).map(pair=> pair);
      this.setState({ historyStats: newHistoryStats })

    })
    .catch(console.log)
  }

  render() {
    const {historyStats} = this.state;
    console.log(Object.values(historyStats));

    return (
      <div>
        {
          historyStats.map(test => ( <p>{test[0]} | {test[1]}</p> ))
        }
      </div>
    )
  }
}


export default Chart;
```

basically we are creating entries like this:

```js
fetch('https://corona.lmao.ninja/v2/historical/germany')
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then((data) => {
    // basically, lets get what it is important, the CASES.
    const { timeline } = data;
    const { cases } = timeline;

    // now cases is an object, lets transform it into an array of 2 entries, the key and value.
    const newHistoryStats = Object.entries(cases).map(pair => pair);
    
    // this will be similar to the render
    newHistoryStats.map(test => console.log(test[0], "|", test[1]))
  })
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it works perfectly in console.log, but when I try to pass in render and return, it throws ***Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined***.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong:


`render() {
    const { newHistoryStats } = this.state;
    
    return (
      <div>
       {newHistoryStats.map(test=><li>{test[0]} | {test[1]}</li>)}
      </div>
    );
  }`

Comment: no, because you have to do:
`render() { const { historyStats } = this.state; return ( <div>{historyStats.map(test=><li>{test[0]} | {test[1]}</li>)} </div> ); }`

Comment: `newHistoryStats` was just an example name :) your state variable will be always be `historyStats `